# Adding field to ArcGIS Map Service without feature access?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-rest-api, geoprocessing-service, map-service

I have published a mapservice without feature access on a remote machine only with a file geodatabase (shapefile on the disk).  Because of limits of authority to create a spatial database(don't have permission to create sqlserver express 2008 for build arcsde to enable feature access for this map service).

However, I have to add a new field into the attribute table of this mapservice via the ArcServer Javascript API .Just like the operation on ArcGIS desktop ,as shown below:

[image]

Is this possible? Any hints to implement it?

Comment: Will need more info. What kind of field so you want to add? Will it be on the basis of some input delivered by the user? What do you mean by limit of authority to create spatial database? Please provide more information as the question is pretty vague. Define your purpose of creating new fields and what kind of spatial database are you using.

Comment: @Sam007 Ok.I will add more info for this question.

Comment: What version of arcgis server are you running?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall 10.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by publishing a gp service with "Add Field" toolbox.To invoked this gp service via javascript api.As shown :[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a C++ SDK of FileGDB API to handle FileGDB, and this may help you. You can build a web service wrapping local operations of FileGDB API, make it RESTful to be consumed by Javascript API.